# How JRE picks up the duplicate classes

Tags: java, runtime, classloader

Assume there are two jars, both contain same class file with same fully qualified name.
Now how JRE sees them, will it throw runtime exception? which I couldn't see in my testing.

How it picks up the class/which will be loaded and which one will be neglected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jre take class from first jar.

Comment: how it determines first jar ;)

Comment: Java search for class in jar (or folder) in which you supply them to it.

Answer (score 0):

It will not cause exceptions because when a class is first referenced (and is not yet loaded), the class loader will look for it in the class path and once it is found, it will be loaded and the search will stop.

Comment: this is not necessarily consistant in any situation with multiple class loaders

Comment: Even if there are multiple independent class loaders, it is true for each class loader that if it doesn't know about the class, it will look for it and once it is found, it will not search for duplicates.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that too but it wasn't because the same class was present in 2 different jars on the class path (which the question refers to) but rather because they were different versions.

Comment: I have seen it with 2 identical jars, in a Connection pooling situation where a database driver was supplied twice, for a common datasource in a servlet container, it can happen.  But yes having different versions is potentially a bigger problem still.

Comment: @Caleryn It might be a very special case. By standard, the ClassLoader loads the first occurrence of the named class in the classpath, this answer is correct.

Comment: @BackSlash my point is simply boils down to the fact that within a single JRE, which is what the question asks, the classpath is not necessarily consistent between classloaders. yes servlet containers are a little weird but they are a very common environment. So I disagree.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use.. if using some IDE it will give you error and duplication or ambiguous class found.. you have to specify the class from which jar file u want to use.. if both having same name and u have added the reference of both in ur project or class.. and using the import statement for both.. it should give u the error..

Comment: Wrong. The JRE will pick up the first class with that name that is found in the classpath.

Comment: Don't just _think_, try it :) It won't give you errors (just tested).

Comment: @Deepak Are you not talking about same class name but different packages?

Comment: @JensKrogsboell no.. if different  package.. then it will work with the included package.. but as @_BackSlash tried it.. I have no comment..

Answer (score 0):

A Single class loader will only ever load one of these although, there is no defined behaviour as to which one may be loaded.  this can cause issues, including `ClassNotFoundException`s even when the two classes are actually exactly the same code prior to compilation.  It will load from the first jar that is locates, but this can vary according to class loader and OS and may produce some odd side effects especially, in older servlet containers.  This situation should be avoided whenever possible.